# The reason(s)/benefit(s) to use realtime operating system instead of while-loop on MCU

Tags: operating-system, controls, real-time, microcontroller, robotics

I'm working on a wheeled-robot platform. My team is implementing some algorithms on MCU to

1. keep getting sensors reading (sonar array, IR array, motor encoders, IMU)
2. receive user command (via a serial port connected to a tablet)
3. control actuators (motors) to execute user commands.
4. keep sending sensor readings to the tablet for more complicated algorithms.

We currently implement everything inside a global while-loop, while I know most of the other use-cases do the very same things with a real-time operating system.

Please tell me the benefits and reasons to use a real-time os instead of a simple while-loop.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your while loop works (i.e. it fulfills the real-time requirements of your system), and it's robust, maintainable, and somewhat extensible, then there probably is no benefit to using a real-time operating system.

But if your while-loop can't fulfill the real-time requirements or is overly complex or over-extended (i.e., any change requires further tuning and tweaking to restore real-time performance), then you should consider another architecture.

An RTOS architecture is one popular next step beyond the super-loop.  An RTOS is basically a tool for managing software complexity.  It allows you to divide a complex set of software requirements into multiple threads of execution.  When done properly, each individual thread has a relatively simple set of requirements and becomes easier to implement.  And thread prioritization can make it easier to fulfill the real-time requirements of the application.  These are basically the benefits of employing an RTOS.

An RTOS is not a panacea, however. An RTOS increases the overall system complexity and opens you up to new types of bugs (such as deadlocks). It requires knowledge and experience to design and implement an RTOS based program effectively.  Consider alternatives such as [Multi-Rate Main Loop Tasking](https://betterembsw.blogspot.com/2015/12/multi-rate-main-loop-tasking.html) or an event-based state machine architecture (such as [QP](http://www.state-machine.com/)).  These alternatives might be simpler, easier to understand, or more compatible with your way of designing software.

Answer (score 1):

The RTOS will provide priority based preemption.  If your code is off parsing a serial command and executing it, it can't respond to anything else until it returns to your beastly loop.  An RTOS will provide the abstractions needed for an instant context switch based on an interrupt event.  Otherwise the worst-case latency of an event response is going to be that of the longest possible excursion out of the main loop, and sometimes you really do need long-running processes.  Such as, for example, to update an LCD panel or respond to USB device enumeration.  Preemption permits you to go off and do these things safe in the knowledge that a 16-bit timer running at the CPU clock isn't going to roll over several times before it's done.  While for simple control jobs a loop is sufficient, the problem starting with it is when you get into something like USB device enumeration it's no longer practical and will need a full rewrite.  By starting with a preemptive framework like an RTOS provides, you have a lot more future flexibility.  But there's definitely a bit more up-front work, and definitely a learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

"Real Time" OS ensures your task periodicity. If you want to read sensors data precisely at every 100msec, simple while loop will not guarantee that. On other hand, RTOS can easily take care of that.
RTOS gives you predictibility. An operation will be executed at given time and it will not be missed.

RTOS gives you Semaphores/Mutex so that your memory will not be corrupted or multiple sources will not access buffers.

RTOS provides message queues which can be useful for communication between tasks.

Yes, you can implement all these features in While loop, but then that's the advantage! You get everything ready and tested.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple huge advantage that a RTOS multitasker has:

Very good I/O performance: an RTOS can set a waiting thread ready as soon as an I/O action that it requested has completed, so latency in handling reads/writes/whatever can be low.  A looped, polled design cannot respond to I/O completions until it gets round to checking the I/O status, (either directly or my polling some volatile flag set by an interrupt-handler).

Indpendent functionality: The ease of implementing isolated subsystems for serial comms, actuators etc. may well be one for you, as suggested in the other answers. It's very reassuring to know that any extra delay in, say some serial exchange, will not adversely affect timing elsewhere. You need to wait a second?  No problem: sleep(1000) and you're done - no effect on the other subsystems:) It's the difference between 'no, I cannot add a network server, it would change all the timing and I would have to retest everything' and 'sure, there's plenty of CPU free, I already have the code from another job and I just need another thread to run it'.

There ae other advanatges that help offset the added annoyance of having to program a preemptive multitasker with its critical sections, semaphores and condvars.
Obviously, if your hardware has multiple cores, the RTOS helps - it is designed to share out available CPU execution cycles just like any other resource, and adding cores means more cycles.

In the end, though, it's the I/O performance and functional isolation that's the big win.

Some of the suggestions in other answers may help, either instead of, or together with, an RTOS.  When controlling multiple I/O hardware, eg. sensors and actuators, an event-driven state-machine is a very good idea indeed.  I often implement that by queueing all events into one thread, (producer-consumer queue), that has sole access to the state data and implements the state-machine, so serializing actions.

Whether the advantages are worth the candle is between you and your requirements:)

Answer (score 0):

RTOS is not instead of while loop - it is while loop + tools which organize your tasks. How do they organize your tasks? Assign priorities to them, decide how much time each one have for a job and/or at what time it should start/end. RTOS also layers your software, i.e harwdare related stuff, application tasks, etc. Aside of that gives you data structures, containers, ready to use interfaces to handle common tasks so you don't have to implement your own i.e allocate some memory for you, lock access for some resources and so on.